# Как в pug создать миксин для вывода товаров однотипных?

Tags: html, css, pug

Привет , перешел на jade. Возникла необходимость воспользовать его возможность для создания миксинов или функции мб, не знаю точно как зовут. Так вот в чем дело, как я знаю можно создать "это" и потом вызывать только указав другие данные как в функции. Покажу пример на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут есть несколько блоков, у них различаются только изображение, цена и количество. Можно создать миксины и просто каждый раз вызывая его с параметрами которые надо. Надеюсь понимайте о чем я.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/278109/ статья и пример https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/Bjbgpv

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример вашего миксина. Структура может быть другой.

//- объявление миксина

```
mixin product(data)
    +b().product
        each item in data.items
            +e('img')(src=item.src, alt='' ,title='')
            +e('span').text !{item.text}
            +e('span').textadd !{item.description}
            +e('span').price !{item.price}
```

//-вызов миксина

```
    +product({'items':[{
            'src'         : 'путь к img',
            'text'        : 'первый товар',
            'description' : '100р',
            'price'       : '1 магазин'
         },{
            'src'         : 'путь к img',
            'text'        : 'второй товар',
            'description' : '200р',
            'price'       : '1 магазин'
        }
    ]})
```